Coefficient of Variation corrected for sample size
I am trying to recreate a method of correction of the Coefficient of Variation, which accounts for sample size, suggested in "Smithson, M., 1982. On relative dispersion: A new solution for some old problems. Quality and Quantity, 16(3), pp.261-271."
The suggested formula is below. In the formula "Q equals the ith data value in a set of researcher specified N values that produce the maximum variation in a response variable".
$$\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2 - N{\bar X}^2\right)}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^N Q_i^2 - N{\bar X}^2\right)}\right) ^{1/2}.$$
Then in the paper "Bedeian, A.G. and Mossholder, K.W., 2000. On the use of the coefficient of variation as a measure of diversity. Organizational Research Methods, 3(3), pp.285-297.", the authors demonstrate the impact of sample size across groups with the same mean and identically distributed scores (see below).

In their first group (A), they calculate a corrected CV (or V") of 0.44, from a sample of only three individuals who have scores of 21, 28 and 35 (mean = 28, sd = 7, sample = 3, uncorrected CV = 0.25).
How have they calculated this correction with only this information? This is admittedly a question of mathematic literacy, so a step-by-step explanation would be appreciated.

Well you need the definition of $Q$(n-sample with mean of $X$ and maximal variance), which requires the range of the data generating process. These are written in your papers and you need to add them to the question. For what it's worth, my guess at $Q$ is (14, 35, 35) but apparently that is wrong.

Being unable to define Q is part of my problem. I have included the definition described in the papers (in my second paragraph), but what this means in simple terms is not clear to me. Can you explain how you made your guess?

"Q equals the ith data value in a set of researcher specified N values that produce the maximum variation in a response variable" of equal mean! Now if the response variable has no limits you can construct samples with  arbitrarily large variance. Paper 1 says, that If the only limit is 0, $Q = (0,0,0,..., \sum X)$. Paper 2 says for their example something about the scores being 7 0-5 items, so I assume the limits are 0 and 35. $\sum X > 70$, so there are no 0s, which is why can't start at 0 and have to use two 35s. But my $V'' = 0.57$, so...
